# tfds.as_numpy() crash after map function

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I tried to use map function to rotate image 20 degree, and read the image data to confirm if it works well as follows.

## **Environment:**

- Google colab
- Tensorflow 2.2

## **Code:**

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import numpy as np
MODE_AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
batch_size = 128

def map_func(image, label):
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.
    angle = 20. * 3.1415926 / 180.0
    image = tfa.image.rotate(images=image, angles=angle, interpolation='NEAREST')
    return image, label

## ... load x_train (images), y_train (labels) ... ##
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
train_data = train_data.shuffle(len(x_train))    
train_data = train_data.map(map_func=map_func, num_parallel_calls=MODE_AUTOTUNE)
train_data = train_data.batch(batch_size)
train_data = train_data.prefetch(buffer_size=MODE_AUTOTUNE) 

datas = tfds.as_numpy(train_data)
for data in datas:
    print(data[0])
    ...
    ## try to plot datas ##
```

It crashed for an unknown reason.
However, when I remove the following code, it works well.

```
    image = tfa.image.rotate(images=image, angles=angle, interpolation='NEAREST')
```

I have no idea. Does the map function works well, but just cannot be read by tfds.as_numpy()?

Comment: the problem seems to be in `tfa` function. Try to convert `angle` to `np.float` or `tf.float`. Also, `map` function actually runs when you run your loop, so it's normal that you get your error at that point.

Comment: `angles`: if images has rank 4 a vector of length num_images, with an angle for each image in the batch. https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/rotate

Comment: I have tried to convert angle to `np.float32` and `tf.float32`, but it still crashed. This problem seems to only occurs in tfa function. There is no problem if I only use tf function, e.g. `tf.image.resize()`. Is it possible to read the image after map function? I would like to observe the state after data augmentation.
I also change the angle shape if rank of vector == 4,  but it still not work. I am not sure about the map function is fed by single data or batch data during training, but `map_func()` seems to run by single data once after `train.map(map_func)`

Comment: I found that `tfa` function crash not only during visualizing, but also during training. There seems to be some problem between `tf` and `tfa`.